# GmailApp.sendEmail is not working in Google form's Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've created a simple form, using the following script:

```
// This function runs when the form is submitted
function onSubmitForm(e) {
  var formResponses = e.values; // Array of form responses
  var email = formResponses[1]; // Assuming email is the second field (adjust the index)

  // Combine form fields into a paragraph
  var paragraph = "Form Data:\n\n";
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    paragraph += formResponses[i] + "\n";
  }

  // Send an email
  sendEmail(email, "Form Submission", paragraph);

}

// This function sends an email
function sendEmail(recipient, subject, body) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Additionaly I've created a trigger which I tested to be worked correctly.
The form is a really simple one with 4 questions.
Link to the form:https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfeoLJA-xYY-EtPrpJaB0uHavFTCAEDLgjTcRtFl-_-wj7EDQ/viewform?usp=sf_link

I can't find a way to debugg the form when a user submit the form.
When a user submit the form, nothing happend, no email is being sent, and Google Form report an error.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation from your question. I have 2 questions. 1. Where is your showing script put in? 2. About `Additionaly I've created a trigger which I tested to be worked correctly.`, I cannot understand the relationship between this and your current issue. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information about the script or any trouble-shooting, and a "view" of the form is not enough. @Tanaike has asked `Where is your showing script put in` He means is it attached to the Form, or to the linked spreadsheet? Which begs the question: have you linked the Form to a spreadsheet?